# Problemas con FORM dentro de FORM - PHP

Tags: php, formularios

tengo un problema con los SUBMIT dentro de mis form...

Tengo un Formulario que envuelve una Tabla, este está encargado de poder exportar la tabla a un Excel (funciona bien).
Dentro de este Form, hay otros 2, que son dependientes de las filas generadas.
En estos se crean botones, Editar y Eliminar, los cuales tienen sus propios Form.
Por alguna razón que desconozco, SOLO la primera fila, está chocando con el `convert_form`.
Esto, supongo, que es por que el botón es de clase `submit` y activa el form erroneo.
PERO lo que me resulta raro, es por que no sucede el mismo problema con el 1er eliminar...

Resumen: Mi primer form, choca con el sumbit del formulario editar, y no se porque o como solucionarlo.

```
<form method="POST" id="convert_form" action="export.php">
<input type="hidden" name="file_content" id="file_content" />
    <button style="float: right; margin-right: 5vw;" type="button" name="convert" id="convert" class="btn btn-primary">Descargar como Excel</button>
    <div id="tabla" class="tablaDatos">
        <table class="miTabla" id="table_content">
            <thead> 
                [codigo del thead]
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                ...
                        echo "  <td class='lineaColumna' style='text-align:center'>
                                <form action='editProducto.php' method='POST'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "' />
                                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Editar'/>
                                </form>
                            </td>";
                        echo "  <td class='lineaColumna' style='text-align:center'>
                                <form action='deleteProducto.php' method='POST'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "' />
                                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' value='Eliminar'/>
                                </form>
                            </td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    $numero++;
                }
                echo "<tr><td class='tbottom' colspan='15'><b>Filas: " . $numero . "</b></td></tr>";
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                mysqli_close($link);
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
```

---

**EDIT*1 : Desconocía el hecho que no se pueden incluir FORM dentro de FORM.**
 Pero aún busco algún tipo de solución a lo que ya tengo.

Comment: A que te refieres por chocar? No ejecuta el submit del propio form?

Comment: El tema, que puse el edit al final... No se pueden poner nested forms. Por lo que, al hacer click en editar, se ejecuta el anterior form, y no el del mismo editar. Creando un error absoluto. Pero creo que ya lo he podido solucionar.

Comment: Terminando de probarlo, hago una respuesta propia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues respondiéndome yo mismo luego de comprobar cosas...

> Advertencia: Está estrictamente prohibido anidar un formulario dentro
> de otro formulario. Anidar formularios no es una buena idea porque
> puede ocasionar comportamientos impredecibles.
> Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

Yo desconocía esto. Por lo que la solución, fue simple y llanamente, mover los form, y colocarlos de manera que estos no se aniden de ningún modo.
En mi caso (y ***reducidamente*** quedaron de este modo:

```
<form method="POST" id="convert_form" action="export.php">
...
</form>
<form action='editProducto.php' method='POST'>
...
</form>
<form action='deleteProducto.php' method='POST'>
...
</form>
```